rack-attack: Rack attack throttling not working
I am trying to limit the api calls using rack attack. I have followed the setup process but throtteling is not working.
steps I followed:

installed rack-attack gem
created rack_attack.rb initializer

class Rack::Attack
  # Throttle requests to the specific endpoint
  throttle('api/flight_search/ip', limit: 5, period: 30.seconds) do |request|
    if request.path == '/api/v1/flight_search' && request.post?
      Rails.logger.info "throttling"
      request.ip
    end
  end

  throttle('get/ip', limit: 5, period: 30.seconds) do |request|
    Rails.logger.info "throttling"
    request.ip
  end

  # Custom response for throttled requests
  self.throttled_responder = lambda do |_env|
    [429, { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }, [{ error: 'Rate limit exceeded. Please try again later.' }.to_json]]
  end
end


added config.middleware.use Rack::Attack to Application.rb
restarted the server

I dont think I have any issue with the setup, but the throttling is not working. The rails log is displayed in the logs but the api executes even though the limit has been crossed.
I tried debugger to check if the throttle is being executed. it seems it is but the api still executes.
I looked around but didnt see any posts related to this. Any one know how to fix this?

Do you have rails caching set up?  How is it configured?

As the debugger mentioned caching is very important with the rack attack. A rack attack needs a cache to store the request counts, especially in throttling. From the documentation - Note that Rack::Attack.cache is only used for throttling, allow2ban and fail2ban filtering. Your cache store must implement increment and write like ActiveSupport::Cache::Store.  In-memory stores which are not backed by an external database will be mostly ineffective because each Ruby process in your deployment will have it's own state.

sorry for the late reply. Apparently I had not setup caching. all I had to do was turn on caching

though I am still unsure about stating and prod
